# pymongo + new relic

Tags: django, pymongo, newrelic

We have a django application server monitored by new relic. We have have used Mysql and MongoDb for data storage in our app. In rpm.newrelic we are having the transaction details of Mysql. We also want to get the transaction details of mongoDb too.

We are using pymongo module for interacting with mongo. I read here that they have included the support of pymongo in their latest python agent. But I am not able to find the documentation for the same. Can anyone point me to some docs ?

Answer (score 1):

At one point we had the same question, and so we built this: https://github.com/Livefyre/pymongo-newrelic

This has some rough edges, but you'll see queries (roughly mapped to SQL terms), and time spent in granular detail.

And while the newer New Relic agents support pymongo directly: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/python/instrumented-python-packages#nosql-database-clients

They do include this caveat (as of this writing):

Note that MongoDB and Redis calls are currently only recorded as transaction breakdown metrics. That is, no rollup metrics are produced and so they will still be shown on the overview dashboard as Python time and not as a separate segment or even as database calls. Also, no specific details of MongoDB queries are captured at this time and so no information will be displayed on the databases page in the UI corresponding to these queries.